# Bootstrap3: Center navlinks on navbar ignoring the brand image

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have my navlinks centered on my navbar. I got this far:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-nav{
    float:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
 }
}
```

This works good in the sense that the links are now centered. BUT, they are not centered on the page - they are centered after the 100px that is being used by the brand image.

Does anyone know how to center them on the page or put in an 100px offset?

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/4py5nmLg/1/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Do you mind tweaking this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4py5nmLg/) to demonstrate what your problem is?

Comment: @JoshCrozier: http://jsfiddle.net/4py5nmLg/1/

As you can see in the result; Home, About & Contact are centered - but they are centered between the space thats left after Project name and then end of the navbar. I would like Home, About & Contact to be centered against the page. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a several different ways to do this. Here are 4 different approaches:

- Absolutely position the `.header`, thereby removing it from the flow. In other words, the `.navbar` will no longer take it into consideration.

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rq6podsa/)

  ```
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-header {
          position: absolute;
      }
      .navbar {
          text-align: center;
      }
      .navbar-nav {
          float: none;
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: top;
      }
  }
  ```

---

- Absolutely position `#navbar` (taking it out of the flow), and use `text-align: center` to center the child element which is now `inline-block`.

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qa5ymp54/)

  ```
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
      #navbar {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0; right: 0;
          text-align: center;
      }
      .navbar-nav {
          float: none;
          display: inline-block;
      }
  }
  ```

---

- Similar to the previous approach, just a different form of centering.

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xe5e1ejc/)

  ```
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
      #navbar {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0; right: 0;
      }
      .navbar-nav {
          float: none;
          margin: 0 auto;
          display: table;
          table-layout: fixed;
      }
  }
  ```

---

- This is another interesting approach for centering elements.

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ardpdv3z/)

  ```
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-nav {
          transform: translateX(-50%);
          left: 50%;
          position: absolute;
      }
  }
  ```